# Difference between capacity growth of ArrayList and HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

In ArrayList, it basically grows to a new size using the grow method:

```
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
...
...
elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}
```

In HashMap, it says it rehashes the content to a new array:

```
Entry[] newTable = new Entry[newCapacity];
...
transfer(...)
```

In arraylist, `Arrays.copyOf` calls `System.arraycopy`. In HashMap, it transfers all the elements in to the new array using while loop. Are there any particular differences between these two collections as both of them eventually create a new array?

Comment: Are there any differences between an array-backed list and a hashtable-backed map? Yes, there are, and so many that it's easier to count similarities than differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `HashMap` needs to transfer the entities by first recalculating all their hashes to decide which buckets to put them in. This is necessary because the index depends on the size of the underlying array. That's why you can't simply use `Arrays.copyOf` or `System.arraycopy` with a `HashMap`.

Note that each `Entry` in a `HashMap` caches the value of its hash for precisely this operation.

Answer (score 1):

A hashmap works completely different to a normal array. The main purpose is that you can access any object in the hashmap directly, without having to iterate over all the elements.
This is done by computing a "hash-value" that acts sort of like a direct index into the map (modulo the size of the map). Only when that slot is already taken, other measures are taken,

If you increase the size of the hashmap the elements have to be rearranged within the hashmap.

For a better explanation, check out e.g. the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashmap).